# Instagram API not returning data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am quite new to the Instagram API. I have been able to authorize myself and get an access token. I used the following URL to search for users, but to no avail:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=3316552483.1677ed0.ab992a6bf15c4bbe99f093e59043547b&count=10

Keep in mind this specific URL will not work because that is not my real access token. However, when I do use my reall access token, I get this response:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "code": 200
   },
   "data": []
}
```

I have scanned the API documentation and I cannot find where my problem is. Keep in mind, I am a sandbox user, and that may have something to do with it.

Comment: have you got the solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are in Sandbox mode, it will only show your and your sandbox user's posts in API response, here is documentation for sandbox:

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from    each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits
>
> The first point is important and it means that the API behaves as if
>   the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users, and the only
>   media ever posted were the last 20 for each of these users.

In the API call, search your username then it will be shown in API response